# Mazda 3 2012 start up problems and violent shaking. Please help

Tags: starting, shaking

For the past few months, my car has been randomly having difficulties starting up. It would just take a few extra seconds to start running. It felt like it needed more power to start. This would only happen once every couple of weeks or so. I've been bringing it to a guy but he has told me to do things such a replace spark plugs, keep my gas over a 1/3 of a tank, replace fuel filter, etc. The problem kept continuing. This morning, I didn't think my car was going to start. I tried to start it twice and it wouldn't start. The car was on, just not running. I tried once more and all of a sudden my lights on the dashboard are rapidly blinking and my car is violently shaking. Anybody have any ideas of what this could be?

Comment: First step is to stop taking it to that guy, he doesn't know what he's doing. Second step is to bring the car (if it's running) or just the battery to an auto parts store and ask them to test the battery.

Comment: No way we can know what this is without more information. The violent shaking is probably from the engine running so poorly (for whatever reason) that it is not able to properly idle. This in turn made all the warning lights come on. Get the codes read to begin to understand where the problem is.